# "Database" report writer for Numbers?

Tags: software-recommendation, numbers, iwork, data, database

I serve on the Board of a Baroque Orchestra and have begun helping them get organized.  The management of the orchestra does not have extensive technical skills so I've endeavored to help provide them with simple and easy to use systems and software to do things like, plan projects and events.

We found a great inexpensive project management application, 
***RationalPlan***.  The software enables us to export all of its data into a set of *Excel* tables which ***iWork's Numbers*** easily reads.

This effectively gives us a well formed database table structure of all the information we need to manage and understand.

Now I need to develop easily run reports on this "data".

While I can develop "reports" in ***Numbers*** itself, non-technical users tend to break them, or delete critical formulas, rows, or columns.

I need a simpler and more robust solution.

Can anyone recommend a report writing application, something like a lite-weight "***Crystal Reports***" that can read and report on these ***Numbers*** tables?

---

Alternatively, I wonder if one could develop a kind of "banded" report template in ***Numbers***.  Does anyone have any experience with something like that?

Comment: Have you tried locking critical tables in Numbers?  If users do not need to touch the data, just see it, locking the table(s) should work provided they don't deliberately unlock them.

Comment: @bjbk - Good idea, but if fear not enough.  End users have extraordinary capacity to break things.